# Hardhat throw Error: yParity mismatch (argument="signature", ...... ) when i try to deploy smartcotnract in sepolia testnet

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Command passed: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia

Hardhat throw error when i try to deploy smart contract in sepolia test using alchemy api:

TypeError: yParity mismatch (argument="signature", value={ "accessList": [  ], "blockHash": null, "blockNumber": null, "chainId": "0xaa36a7", "from": "0x19....", "gas": "0x362f0", "gasPrice": "0xf9abdac5",

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution ?? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the <key> value for alchemy api?

Comment: Hey @AlexeySmirnov actually, I am also facing this problem, this has to do something with the getTransaction function in ethers, and it was fixed with ethers 6.6.4, so updating the version should fix it. But I am facing problems updating the version. I've also opened a discussion here - https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/4568

Comment: @Zartaj Afser Thank you this solved it for me!

Comment: Cheers @DobromirKirov 